# Generate URL to external route with UrlGenerator

Tags: php, symfony1, silex

With Silex (the PHP micro framework), it's possible to give names to existing controllers, so that we can easily generate urls to them later. Example:

```
$app->get('/gallery', function () {...})
    ->bind('gallery');

// Later on, in a template
{{ path('gallery') }}
```

I think this is really useful and I can't live without it.

But is it possible to register a route to an external website ? Say I'd like to generate urls to a google search, kind of

```
{{ path('google', {'search':'symfony'}) }}
// Would render to http://google.com/search?q=symfony
```

I take any idea :) Thx for your help !

Comment: Why do you need that? Why not directly use plain html? ie: `<a href="http://google.com/search?q=symfony">Symfony on Google</a>`

Comment: Because I have several different links that must be used in several different places. And these links are different across environments, so I just can't hardcode it.

Comment: So put those link bases in to config. Or extend the "path" Twig Extension with your feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path()` is a Twig Extension for routing. Routing is to route an incoming URL to a controller action.

You can, however, create your own twig extension if you want a helper to easily create those standard outgoing URLs.

Take a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

You could then create an extension that turns `{{ google('search string') }}` into a URL. Only the imagination is your boundary.